# What does this Outlook icon mean?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I've made a VBA code to save all attachments from all mails in an Outlook folder to a physical folder on my computer. When testing I came across this error, When the email I receive has a "normal" email icon, everything works as expected. But when it has this icon as you see in my screenshot, the VBA code gives this error:

> error message 438: "object doesn't support this property or method".

[image]

I also cannot view the attachments as a normal mail. What I can do, is `select one mail > File > Save Attachments`

So my questions are: What does the circled icon before an email mean? What is it's name and is there a way to bypass this inability to view/save the attachments right away?

> Note: of course I've searched Google but the solutions it provides only apply to the regular email type. Also, the mails with this icon are "bouncers"; auto-reply mails from a server when a mail isn't send to a valid address.

**EDIT:**

This is the line of code that generates the error:

```
For Each Item In SubFolder.Items

  For Each aAttachment In Item.Attachments
      If LCase(Right(aAttachment.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
          FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & I & aAttachment.FileName 'Item.SenderName is the error generator
          aBijlage.SaveAsFile FileName
          I = I + 1
      End If
  Next aAttachment
Next Item
```

Comment: Looks like a Email Read Receipt. You could use a simple error handler for that `On Error Resume Next` as these would not be seperate emails on their own.

Comment: @izzymo I have it, but these 'email read receipt' contain a .msg attachment with the original mail, which I need

Comment: Wouldn't that attachment by the original email that you sent.

Comment: I usually get the messages having such icon if delivery has failed, eg due to recipient's mailbox is full, or wrong email address. Sent by Microsoft Exchange Server 2007. The message contains a list of recipients delivery has failed to, and some diagnostic info.

Comment: @omegastripes I know, it also contains the original mail. As it seems there isn't any simple way of saving these, so I'm now working on a macro to loop through every mail and save the attachment in a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
    set vItems = SubFolder.Items
    dim Item As Object
    'PR_HASATTACH = true
    set Item = vItems.Find("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B"" = 'true' ")
    while Not (Item is Nothing)
      if Item.Class = olMail Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
        For Each aAttachment In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(aAttachment.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & I & aAttachment.FileName 'Item.SenderName is the error generator
                aAttachment.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next aAttachment
      End If
      set Item = vItems.FindNext
    wend
```

Comment: Debugging finds that Item.Class == olReport (46)

Comment: Solved it! thanks to you. The ReportItem doesn't have a `SenderName` member, so I just deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Non Delivery Report. See [What do the Outlook icons mean?](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/icons.htm) for more information.

> the macro gives error message 438: "object doesn't support this property or method".

What line of code generates the error? What code do you use? Could you be more specific?

Comment: As you see in my question, all methods with `Item` generates an error. This doesn't happen with normal "read message"

Comment: Try to declare it as a MailItem object and check out the MessageClass property before casting the item.

Comment: Let's try! Apart from this question, is there any way to 'convert' a ndr to a message/normal email?

Comment: Now I get Type Mismatch on `For Each Item In SubFolder.Items'

Comment: Solution: apparantly a NDR isn't a MailItem object, but a ReportItem. And ReportItem doesn't have a SenderName member, so after deleting that things started moving :)